# Speeding up aggregation queries on large dataset mongodb

Tags: mongodb, performance, apache-spark

I have 48.919.581 documents stored inside mongoDB ( ~11 GB ) on which i need to perform aggrergations. The aggregation result takes too long , we're speaking of minutes when I need those results almost instantaneously.

I thought of using Apache Spark to create vues with pre-computed data and perform aggregations on those views. I created one view to test with spark running locally on my machine  : it had 17 million documents and the aggregation query is still very slow.
Plus it would take too much storage to store all of the views.

I am working on a computer with 12GB ram and 2 cores ( 4 logical cores), but the production server on which the application is to be deployed has 128GB ram and 8 cores ( 16 logical cores).

I don't have professional experience so I can not estimate how much would the queries take on a production server.

Is there a way to speed up the aggregations? if not is there another database that is more suitable for aggregations?

Comment: I'm sure you already have tried this, but mongo let's you explain your query, and the path it took. Make a few indexes, and test it out using the explain?

Comment: I did indeed but aggregations do not use indexes unless you specify limit,match, sort and skip in the aggregation pipeline.